# Powershell Replace 2 Spaces with 0 Spaces Accross Directory

Tags: powershell, replace

Powershell question.

I need a command that will do a find and replace for ^  ^ (2 spaces between the hats) and replace it with ^^ (no space between the hats).

Sample data:
123456^100.00^10/14/2013^  ^^Columbus^

Want the result to be:
123456^100.00^10/14/2013^^^Columbus^

I would also like this command to perform this find and replace across all files in a given directory, say C:\SampleDirectory*.*

Any help you guys can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`$string = "12456^100.00^10142013^  ^^Columbus"`

`$string -replace "\^\s\s\^\^","^^^"`

To do it across all files just do a get-childitem and a foreach loop... Although I can't figure out how you would get a file name with slashes in it.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/03/21/use-powershell-to-replace-text-in-strings.aspx